# Issues loading image from /Assets/ in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm having some really weird problems trying to load a file pragmatically into my project to save to a local folder.

I can load the file fine in my .xaml code, as so:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="Image" UriSource ="/Assets/Submandibular_oedema.jpg" />
```

And I can display that image on my page. However, when I try to load the image and use it in my xaml.cs code like this

```
uriMyFile = new Uri("/Assets/Submandibular_oedema.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

It cannot find the file and as a result, won't let me do anything with the URI.

For background, my aim is to get the image stream then save it to a local folder.

I know it'll be a stupid little problem, but I can't find any solutions to it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this is WP 7/8 application or a WPF application? Please remove the tags that are not appropriate to this question.

Comment: Why not using System.IO.StreamReader?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Update after Starktastics comment:**
I finally understood your problem: you need the `Application.GetResourceStream` method to retrieve a stream of your resource, read from that stream and write it to a file stream.

```
var streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
var stream = streamResourceInfo.Stream;
var byteBuffer = new byte[stream.Length];
using (stream)
{
    stream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
}
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("photo.jpg", FileMode.Create))
{
    fileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
}
```

I've updated the solution that you can download [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14810011/LoadImageInCode.zip).

**Original answer:**

If you use a WPF application, make sure that the asset you added to your project is to Build Action 'Resource'. You can check that in the properties pane after you clicked the file.

In any case, your syntax for the URI is correct. I checked it in a small project myself and it works. You can download it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14810011/LoadImageInCode.zip) (DropBox link)

Feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: I changed it to Resource and still isn't working. I think I'm kind of mixed up about what I'm doing with it after, I need the Stream for the image so my next line is 'Stream imageStream = App.GetResourceStream(uriMyFile).Stream;' then I save it to a folder with a bit of code which I use without issue elsewhere in my code. The line above is calling a 'NullReferenceException', which I assume is due to the URI not being built initiated successfully. Do you see any issue with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try full path (specify your project assembly)

```
uriMyFile = new Uri("/YourAssemblyName;component/Assets/Submandibular_oedema.jpg",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
uriMyFile=new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/YourImage.png"));
```

This works for me while trying to show a diffrent map icon for each place.